# Display camera preview on Raspberry Pi Android things

Tags: android, kotlin, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, android-things

I was working on an app that runs on a Raspberry Pi with Android Things and is supposed to show a Camera preview onto an external display and there's a push button attached to the demo which on being pressed, captures a picture from the camera and does some computation on that captured image.

I've successfully completed the second part, but while trying to get a camera preview on the screen, the app crashes for me.
I got my RPi yesterday and I tried running the Camera2 sample on Github (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) but I ran into the same issue as before.

```
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
2019-04-01 00:18:19.670 4625-4650/com.example.android.camera2basic W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:372: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
2019-04-01 00:18:19.682 4625-4650/com.example.android.camera2basic E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
```

I have also tried modifying the width and height of the Preview inside ImageReader to one of the compatible sizes as shown on my Android things console (see the JPEG section in the screenshot below) but that didn't help.

[image]

However, I did find a repo on Github that gives me realtime preview on a RPi board, but the downside is that it has a terrible Framerate (10-15 FPS).
Repository Link : https://github.com/harshithdwivedi/CameraDemoForAndroidThings

I'd appreciate any ideas or pointers on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented in [another issue](https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell/issues/10#issuecomment-313826889) the RPI3 camera HAL only support one target surface at a time, this apparently come from a [limitation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130806) of the underlying V4L2 implementation.

The following workaround should be possible:

- for preview: use a [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) as the target surface
- when taking picture: in the [CaptureCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback) use [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) to grab the raw frame from the surface

You can find a tentative example based on the `android-Camera2Basic` kotlin sample: [here](https://github.com/proppy/android-Camera2Basic/commit/0155b482bba7c5efde59d329283614586fc33b6a)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!
I tried your sample and in order for the preview to be initialized; I had to add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the manifest.

Post which the camera is initialized but the preview still fails with the following message in the error logs : 

https://pastebin.com/ebfnMdKA

Comment: @the-dagger, I was able to get the preview working on the RPI3 by removing the focus management: https://github.com/proppy/android-Camera2Basic/commit/ef59429867009dcecd7608c6dbbd4dac89aa65d5 feel free to give it another try !

Comment: Whoa, it works now!
Thanks a ton, I was suck on this for more than a month now.

Comment: which FPS did you get?

Comment: It's close to 20-25 FPS now; which is quite ok.
Do you know of any way that might help increase the FPS? 

The default camera testing utility that comes bundled in with the Android Things OS seems to have a better frame rate that what I'm getting right now.

Here's a quick demo of the current scenario : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5H6YoD64bgY

Comment: @the-dagger for me the Launcher preview is way slower than the application (I think the former might be reading raw frame with a `ImageReader` and bliting them manually to an `ImageView`)

Comment: Hi @proppy I was playing around with the sample and it looks like on calling `lockFocus()`, the `captureStillPicture()` method is called twice!

I'm doing some network calls on the received bitmap inside the `PixelCopy.request()` and hence as a result the network calls are being duplicated.

Do you have an idea on what might be happening here?

The logs and debugger confirm that the method is indeed being called twice