# when tensorflow-demo(detectorActivity) is implemented in android things, it says "session 0: failed to create capture session; configuration failed"

Tags: android, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

ive been trying to implement the tensorflow-demo detectoractivity in android things but black screen just appears. here is the logcat

```
2019-04-24 13:55:00.735 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
2019-04-24 13:55:00.736 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo E/zygote: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)
2019-04-24 13:55:00.736 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
2019-04-24 13:55:01.132 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
2019-04-24 13:55:04.607 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 1718ms, TensorFlow version: 1.13.1
2019-04-24 13:55:04.614 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
2019-04-24 13:55:04.618 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: -270
2019-04-24 13:55:04.619 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Initializing at size 640x480
2019-04-24 13:55:04.669 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo W/tensorflow: ImageUtils: Native library not found, native RGB -> YUV conversion may be unavailable.
2019-04-24 13:55:04.698 5046-5091/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Opening camera preview: 640x480
2019-04-24 13:55:04.830 5046-5091/org.tensorflow.demo W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:372: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
2019-04-24 13:55:04.854 5046-5091/org.tensorflow.demo E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
2019-04-24 13:55:05.895 5046-5094/org.tensorflow.demo D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-04-24 13:55:06.025 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/Choreographer: Skipped 320 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

i also run this on mobile device but it shows its camera compared to running it in android things with raspberry pi. here's the logcat

```
96 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
2019-04-24 15:04:09.397 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo E/zygote64: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)
2019-04-24 15:04:09.397 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
2019-04-24 15:04:09.468 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
2019-04-24 15:04:10.838 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 984ms, TensorFlow version: 1.13.1
2019-04-24 15:04:10.841 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
2019-04-24 15:04:10.844 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: 90
2019-04-24 15:04:10.846 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Initializing at size 640x480
2019-04-24 15:04:10.875 22508-22520/org.tensorflow.demo I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
2019-04-24 15:04:10.877 22508-22520/org.tensorflow.demo I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=18KB
2019-04-24 15:04:10.877 22508-22520/org.tensorflow.demo I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2019-04-24 15:04:10.882 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo W/tensorflow: ImageUtils: Native library not found, native RGB -> YUV conversion may be unavailable.
2019-04-24 15:04:10.936 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/PermissionManager: camera remind result:true
2019-04-24 15:04:10.936 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/CameraManager: open camera: 0, package name: org.tensorflow.demo
2019-04-24 15:04:10.936 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/HwSystemManager: pkgName = org.tensorflow.demo pid = 22508uidOf3RdApk = 10158permType = 0permCfg=1
2019-04-24 15:04:10.937 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/BackgroundPermManager: pkgName: org.tensorflow.demo,pid: 22508 ,uidOf3RdApk: 10158 ,permType: 0 ,permCfg: 1
2019-04-24 15:04:10.943 22508-22529/org.tensorflow.demo I/CameraManagerGlobal: single back camera, do not need hide aux camera, device number: 2
2019-04-24 15:04:10.943 22508-22529/org.tensorflow.demo I/CameraManagerGlobal: single back camera, do not need hide aux camera, device number: 2
2019-04-24 15:04:11.003 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Opening camera preview: 640x480
2019-04-24 15:04:11.008 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo E/BufferQueueProducer: [] Can not get hwsched service
2019-04-24 15:04:11.130 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 5
2019-04-24 15:04:11.132 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/Choreographer: Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-04-24 15:04:11.429 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 0 at size 307200
2019-04-24 15:04:11.431 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 1 at size 153599
2019-04-24 15:04:11.434 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 2 at size 153599
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the Android Things [image classifier sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-tensorflow-imageclassifier) using TensorFlow Lite to see how to operate the camera and run inference on Android Things.

Android Things devices have a few restrictions around the number of camera streams that can be open simultaneously and the supported camera parameters. This often means camera samples written for Android phones don't work unmodified. You can use the sample I linked as a basis to work from.

**EDIT:** Regarding processing data from a live preview, you may want to look into the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636748/display-camera-preview-on-raspberry-pi-android-things) about capturing and previewing simultaneously on Android Things.

Comment: is it possible to continuously open the camera and classify it like without the button thing?

Comment: Yes, but because only a single stream can be active at a time, you cannot create a session that captures to BOTH a surface texture (for UI preview) and an ImageReader (for processing) like the capture demo does. You can only stream to a single target at a time.

Comment: what do you mean by i can only stream to a single target at a time? im sorry im new to this thing. does that mean i cant implement real time recognition?

Comment: You can't call `addTarget()` more than once to a capture session. If you look at the original code you tried to run, it's called twice to add two targets...one for `ImageReader` and once for the UI `SurfaceTexture`.